# Angular - Karma test for disabled input not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component which is a switch component, it has an input which can be disabled using an `@Input() disabled` property. So I wrote this test which grabs the original model value, updates the component's `disabled` property, simulates a click on the input and then checks whether the model changed.

This does not work:

```
it('should not update the model if disabled is true', () => {

  const model = !!component.model;

  component.disabled = true;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  input.click();

  expect(component.model).toBe(model);
});
```

However, if I set the disabled state directly on the input with `input.disabled = true`, it works.

Strange thing is that in the Karma browser tab, I can see that the switch is in fact disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Wrap code after `fixture.detectChanges();` in `fixture.whenStable().then(...)`

```
it('should not update the model if disabled is true', () => {

  const model = !!component.model;

  component.disabled = true;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    input.click();
    expect(component.model).toBe(model);
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain your solution? Why is it required to wrap it in `whenStable`?